# How to make fixed floating element stop at #footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is the code I am using to fix a sidebar as the user scrolls. As of now, it overlaps with my footer. How can I make it stop at a certain point or when it hits the footer?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('.pageheaderwrap').length) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 362) {
                $(".sidebar-left").css({
                    "position": "fixed",
                    "top": 0
                });
            } else {
                $(".sidebar-left").css({
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "top": "255px"
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 230) {
                $(".sidebar-left").css({
                    "position": "fixed",
                    "top": 0
                });
            } else {
                $(".sidebar-left").css({
                    "position": "absolute",
                    "top": "125px"
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Cybernate: Was just about to fix the indenting myself. :-)

Comment: You could figure out the distance between the two elements (footer and sidebar), and when that distance <= 0 you could stop moving the sidebar down. Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225563/get-relative-position-between-2-dom-elements-using-javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Here is something that might work for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/y3qV5/7/

The jquery plugin that is doing this sets elements fixed whatever margin from the top of the page.  With an optional limit, it will unfix the element and have it continue to scroll up the page, keeping it away from your footer.  You would set the limit to the top of your footer, plus the height of whatever your target element is.

Here is the code usage for this scenario (the fiddle above):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cart').scrollToFixed({
        marginTop: 10,
        limit: $('#footer').offset().top 
    });
});
```

Here is the link to the plugin and its source:

https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed

Answer (score 1):

Why not eliminate all the javascript and do it with CSS:

```
.sidebar-left {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px; /* height of your footer */
}
```

Comment: I imagine he wants it stuck to the bottom until it collides with the footer, then sticks to the top of the footer.

Comment: Ahhh, in that case, he needs to set bottom: footer-height when he gets to the footer

Comment: Yeah, a perfect example of what I'm trying to achieve is  the rightside map on on Yelp: http://www.yelp.com/search?find_desc=food&ns=1&find_loc=Santa+Rosa%2C+CA

Answer (score 0):

I see the easiest way to reach this is to use `position: sticky;` instead of `position: fixed;` and give the parent of this section `position: relative;` to keep the sticky container within the parent container borders.