# jQuery distanceTo() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a code to try and find the distance between two elements: `<div class='feature'>` and `<div class='social'>` and if the value is less than 0, then `<div class='social'>` will be hidden.

I cannot see why it doesn't work so I'm asking your help.
Here is the code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
  <script>
    var distance = $(.feature).distanceTo($(.social));
    if (distance < 0) {
      $(".social").css("display","none");
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class='feature' style='width:500px;height:200px;background-color:#333333'>
    <!--a lot of content in here-->
  </div>
  <div class='social'>
    <a href='https://www.facebook.com/vosocks'><img id='facebook' width='50' height='50'  class='social' src='http://www.vosocks.co.uk/facebook%20logo.png'/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=''><span class='socialtxt'>Like us on Facebook!</span></a><br>
    <a href='https://twitter.com/vosocks'><img id='twitter' class='social' width='50' height='50'  src='http://www.vosocks.co.uk/twitterlogo.png'/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='https://twitter.com/vosocks'><span class='socialtxt'>Follow us on Twitter!</span></a><br>
    <a href='http://instagram.com/VoSock'><img id='instagram' width='50' height='50' class='social' src='http://www.vosocks.co.uk/instagramlogo.png'/></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=''><span class='socialtxt'>Follow us on Instagram!</span></a><br>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe `var distance = $('.feature').distanceTo($('.social'));`, with quotes

Comment: What's not working about it?  You realize your code will only run once, when the page is loaded.  Right?

Comment: i didn't know this method... Coming from a plugin or what?

Comment: Need your "distanceTo" code to figure it out

Comment: And please, use your console in debugging purpose, you should be able at least to fix syntax errors

Comment: I got the method from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/225563/get-relative-position-between-2-dom-elements-using-javascript

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find distance between two elements, use [Jquery's .offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/).

[Here is the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3n5Xt/2/)

I have added an id to your div with social class to make it unique and here is the example code.

```
var distance = $('#social_buttons').offset().top;
 alert(distance);
```

Hope it helps